# navigateToURL after a period of inactivity in Flash

Tags: flash

I would like to have my application restart if the mouse isn't moved in three minutes. I use "navigateToURL" to return to the first scene, but how would I implement such a timed event using actionscript 3?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple - you need to use two event listeners:

1. MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event listener
2. TimerEvent.TIMER event listener

you will also need a Timer object

So here's the code

```
    //private timer var in your class
    private var myLittleTimer:Timer;

    //This is your main function, where you adding all the event listeners
    //IMPORTANT NOTE:
    //We can only track mouse movement over the flash stage in a DisplayObject that
    //has the link to the main stage
    //For example, your main SPRITE
    yourMainFunction():void{
        //Timer initialization
        this.myLittleTimer = new Timer(3000, 1);
        this.myLittleTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, lazinessDetector);
        this.myLittleTimer.start();

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }
    private function init(e:Event):void{
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        //THIS IS THE ENTRANCE POINT
        //do not use stage object before the sprite has been added to the stage
        //as it will cause a null object exception

        //We add a MOUSE_MOVE event listener to the stage to track the moment when
        //the mouse has moved
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    }
    private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void{
        this.myLittleTimer.reset();
        this.myLittleTimer.start();
        //This function will reset the "countdown" timer and start it over again.
    }
    private function lazinessDetector(e:TimerEvent):void {
        //YOUR URL REDIRECT CODE GOES HERE
    }
```